# How shared in social networks from webview link-appweb with android-studio?

Tags: android-studio, webview, shared

I have a webapp that works with my `webview`.

From:

```
webView.loadUrl ("file: ///android_asset/index.html");
```

It works well.

I need to click on my webapp `<a href="#">` share news `</a>` to open system share dialogs on Android to share the news. (image below)

[image: a busy cat]

How do I do it?

I have tried with:

- navigator.share with javscript but it doesn't work (it only works with `httpS: //`, but it can't from `file: ///android_asset/index.html)`

How to send the data (from my webapp), for example title, text, image (if possible) and open system share dialogs to share?

I need examples for the best known as instagram, whatsapp, facebook, etc.

Thanks for your help.